# Facebook Api Get all photos with limit

Tags: facebook

I try to get all uploaded photos include all album with limit

```
me?fields=albums.limit(2){photos{source}} // This only limit album
```

If i use

```
me?fields=albums{photos.limit(10){source}}  // This will limit photos inside album
```

But i don't want limit album and photos separately 
I want limit total result it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an overall limit like "only give me 10 photos from all albums" is not possible via the normal `albums` endpoint. You can filter/limit in your application to create an overall limit.

Or, if you want only the photos the user uploaded himself, you could use

```
GET /{user-id}/photos?type=uploaded&limit=100
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Reading